# how can I check if windows 10 is updating drivers?

Tags: windows, driver, updates

looks like when windows is updating drivers it will first disables drivers install according setupapi.dev.log

If my 3'th party driver is installed at the same time it will fail due my inf file is in use:
'''
Error 32: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
!!!  inf:           Error (0x00000020) searching published INFs.
'''

after windows driver update is completed and it has enabled drivers install my 3'th party driver install works again.

how can I check is driver update is disabled ?
or can I use CMP_WaitNoPendingInstallEvents() to check if windows driver updates are ongoing ?